# Question on derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Please i have a small question:

i have a function $f(t,u(t))$, how to express the first derivativ of $f$ with respect to $u$ at $0$ using limites ?

i.e. how to express $f'_u(t,0)$ using limits ??

Please help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $f(t,u(t))$, people will understand that you have a map of the variable $t$: $t \mapsto f(t,u(t))$. Therefore it is meaningless to differentiate "with respect to $u$".
On the other hand, if you have a function $(t,u) \mapsto f(t,u)$, then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(t,0)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{f(t,\varepsilon)-f(t,0)}{\varepsilon}.
$$